# The Readers/Writers Problem priority

Tags: java, concurrency

I developed a solution for the reader/writer problem in java (some information on this http://lass.cs.umass.edu/~shenoy/courses/fall08/lectures/Lec11.pdf).

However I am not sure how to modify the code to either favor writers or give both reader and writer same priority. What type of this problem is my code and how do I see it?

```
public class ReaderWriter{


    int numberOfReaders;
    int numberOfWriters;

    public ReaderWriter(){
        this.numberOfReaders = 0;
        this.numberOfWriters = 0;
    }

    public synchronized void requestRead(){
        while(this.numberOfWriters > 0)
            wait();

        this.numberOfReaders++;
    }

    public synchronized void releaseRead(){
        this.numberOfReaders--;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void requestWrite(){
        while(this.numberOfReaders > 0 || this.numberOfWriters > 0)
            wait();

        this.numberOfWriters++; 
    }

    public synchronized void releaseWrite(){
        this.numberOfWriters--;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version favors readers (and can starve writers).
Here is a modified version that favors writers (and can starve readers):

```
    int numberOfReaders;
    int numberOfWriters;
    int numberOfRequestedWriters;  // ++

    public ReaderWriter(){
        this.numberOfReaders = 0;
        this.numberOfWriters = 0;
        this.numberOfRequestedWriters = 0; // ++
    }

    public synchronized void requestRead(){
        while(this.numberOfWriters > 0  // --
              || this.numberOfRequestedWriters > 0) // ++
            wait();

        this.numberOfReaders++;
    }

    public synchronized void releaseRead(){
        this.numberOfReaders--;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void requestWrite(){
        this.numberOfRequestedWriters++; // ++
        while(this.numberOfReaders > 0 || this.numberOfWriters > 0)
            wait();
        this.numberOfRequestedWriters--; // ++

        this.numberOfWriters++; 
    }

    public synchronized void releaseWrite(){
        this.numberOfWriters--;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused why you used `numberOfWriters` instead of a boolean to track writes in progress.

Is there a specific reason, or was it just a quick solution (i.e. does the value ever go above 1? I don't think it should?)

Comment: @Federico You are correct -- if everything goes right `numberOfWriters` should only be 0 or 1 so a boolean could be used. Probably did it this way for consistency with `numberOfReaders`.

Answer (score 0):

To control how locks are distributed, you need to maintain a queue of waiting threads.  Unless the section of code you are protecting is expensive, a simple lock may be better.